# screenshot using html2canvas needed to be saved as psd in folder

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, coffeescript

i need to save take a screeshot of a div in html page which contains four images . I successfully created that and saved the screenshot of the div to server in image format but the client now requires that it should be saved as psd file. it doesnt matter if it have layers or not it could be image file which saved as psd and can be opened using photoshop.

Comment: Who thinks this question deserves an upvote? Please, an upvote is to denote _The question shows research effort; it is useful and clear_ Those criteria do not apply to this question

Comment: I dont get, why it needs to be a psd File. Can't photoshop open regular images? If layers don't matter, I don't see a difference

Comment: Its just client requirement and he doesn't wanna understand so please if someone could tell me if it is possible to do so.

Comment: Save the state of the canvas as json. and retrieve it when ever you want.

Comment: i need the file extension to be .psd as for now i am saving the image as jpg using file_put_contents() but when i change the extension in the file_put_contents to .psd it dosent works

Answer (score 1):

I will try to respond to your question.

I suggest you to install ImageMagick to your server if you use linux or mac.
Then, via php (with `shell_exec` for example) convert your png or jpg or other image type to psd with the command like `convert input.jpg output.psd`, or for more option see [the official docs](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php)